# Trying to define, evaluate and integrate r functions recursively in loop

Tags: r, list, function, recursion, integration

[This is the intergral I'm trying to evaluate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDZZx.png)

What I'm trying to do is put the g_k(x,s) into a list so I can recursively use them in the loop.

```
n = 500
k = 3
g_1 <- 1
rho <- sqrt( ((k-1)*(n-k))/(k*(n-k+1)) )
tau2 <- (sqrt( n / (k*(n-k+1))))

g_lst <- c()

#Coded discretely for k=1,2,3,4

g1 <- function(x,s){ return( 1 ) }
g_lst <- c(g_lst,g1)

g2 <- function(x,s){ return( integrate(function(y){g_lst[[1]](y,s)*(dnorm(y,rho*x,tau2)+dnorm(y,-rho*x,tau2))},0,s)[[1]] ) }
g_lst <- c(g_lst,g2)

g3 <- function(x,s){ return( integrate(function(y){g_lst[[2]](y,s)*(dnorm(y,rho*x,tau2)+dnorm(y,-rho*x,tau2))},0,s)[[1]] ) }
g_lst <- c(g_lst,g3)

g4 <- function(x,s){ return( integrate(function(y){g_lst[[3]](y,s)*(dnorm(y,rho*x,tau2)+dnorm(y,-rho*x,tau2))},0,s)[[1]] ) }
g_lst <- c(g_lst,g4)


#Trying to generalise to k=1,2,...,k
g_lst2 <- c()
g1 <- function(x,s){ return( 1 ) }
g_lst2 <- c(g_lst2,g1)

for (i in 1:3){
  
  i <- force(i)
  gk <- function(x,s){ return( integrate(function(y){g_lst[[i]](y,s)*(dnorm(y,rho*x,tau2)+dnorm(y,-rho*x,tau2))},0,s)[[1]] ) }
  force(gk)
  g_lst2 <- c(g_lst2,gk)
}
```

Here are the corresponding values im getting from evualting the functions from the list. g_lst is giving me the correct values whereas g_lst2 for all i>=1 g_lst[[i]] is giving me the value of the g_lst2[4].
From the threads I could find on stack exchange I feel i need to use the force() function but for the way I've used it is not helping.

```
g_lst2[[2]](2,2)
#[1] 1.811419
g_lst2[[3]]](2,2)
#[1] 1.811419
g_lst2[[4]](2,2)
#[1] 1.811419

g_lst[[2]](2,2)
#[1] 0.7380149
g_lst[[3]](2,2)
#[1] 1.156224
g_lst[[4]](2,2)
#[1] 1.811419
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `force()` inside a `for` loop doesn't really help because `for` doesn't create a new scope. You want to create a generating function instead to build your list. For example

```
#Trying to generalise to k=1,2,...,k
g_lst2 <- c()
g1 <- function(x,s){ return( 1 ) }
g_lst2 <- c(g_lst2,g1)

for (i in 1:3){
  make_gk <- function(i) {
    force(i)
    function(x,s){ return( integrate(function(y){g_lst2[[i]](y,s)*(dnorm(y,rho*x,tau2)+dnorm(y,-rho*x,tau2))},0,s)[[1]] ) }
  }
  gk <- make_gk(i)
  g_lst2 <- c(g_lst2,gk)
}
```

Note that we are calling `force()` inside the function because that creates a new scope.
This will return the desired values

```
g_lst2[[2]](2,2)
# [1] 0.7380149
g_lst2[[3]](2,2)
# [1] 1.156224
g_lst2[[4]](2,2)
# [1] 1.811419
```

Alternatively you could use `lapply` which would take care of the forcing for you

```
g_lst2 <- c()
g1 <- function(x,s){ return( 1 ) }
g_lst2 <- c(g_lst2,g1)

g_lst2 <- c(g_lst2, lapply(1:3, function(i) 
  function(x,s){ return( integrate(function(y){g_lst2[[i]](y,s)*(dnorm(y,rho*x,tau2)+dnorm(y,-rho*x,tau2))},0,s)[[1]] ) }
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use recursion to generalize. Below are two ways to do this

```r
n <- 500
k <- 3
rho <- sqrt( ((k-1)*(n-k))/(k*(n-k+1)) )
tau2 <- (sqrt( n / (k*(n-k+1))))



g <- function(x,s,k){
  if(k == 1) 1
  else 
    integrate(function(y)g(y,s, k-1)*(
      dnorm(y, x*rho, tau2) + dnorm(y, -x*rho, tau2)),0,s)[[1]]
}

g(2,2,1)
#> [1] 1
g(2,2,2)
#> [1] 0.7380149
g(2,2,3)
#> [1] 1.156224
g(2,2,4)
#> [1] 1.811419
```

The second way is to return a function then evaluate the function at the points needed

```r
g1 <- function(k){
  if(k == 1) function(...) 1
  else  function(x,s)
    integrate(function(y)g1(k-1)(y,s)*(
      dnorm(y, x*rho, tau2) + dnorm(y, -x*rho, tau2)),0,s)[[1]]
}
g1(1)(2,2)
#> [1] 1
g1(2)(2,2)
#> [1] 0.7380149
g1(3)(2,2)
#> [1] 1.156224
g1(4)(2,2)
#> [1] 1.811419
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Of course this method given is slow as it does not save the intermediate results. ie if you compute `g(2,2,10)` then if you need `g(2,2,8)` you should not compute it but rather read it from the table of already computed `g(2,2,10)`. But the method provided above does compute the value again. We can skip this process by using memoization: